# Making authenticated requests

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using form authentication and role based access. 
I want to make all the subsequent request as an authentication request using the access token.
I refer **Loopback-example-access-control** example, but not get a clear idea.
In this example, they pass access token using query string. My question is I want to make all the request as authenticated using access-token without pass query string or header.

Any other alternative way is available?
I need demo application that includes authentication and authorization, except loopback-example-access-control example.
Please help me, I am new to strong loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only three ways to send data to a server: path/query string, headers, and the request body. Since you don't want to use the query string (which is good, you really shouldn't) and you don't want to use a header (which is the most common and currently the industry standard) then you are left with only the request body. That's not a great choice either, and not supported by default in LoopBack, you would have to code that up yourself.

The right solution here is to use the `Authorization` header and send the access token in there with each request.

And just to be clear, this really has nothing to do with LoopBack, this is just token-based authentication basics. You *must* pass the token with each request, that's how the system works, there is no alternative.